# Cosmos DB Failover Alert?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-application-insights, failover, azure-monitoring

Is it possible to create an alert, or otherwise view a metric or log that will report that a Cosmos DB Account has undergone a failover to another region, either automatically or manually?

In the past I've detected this on the client-side by comparing the `WriteEndpoint` against previously completed calls; then log a custom event to Application Insights indicating a failover had occurred if the write region changed.

But I would like a pure server-side (service-side) way to report this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create an alert for a regional failover. Enable control plane diagnostics as explained in [How to audit Azure Cosmos DB control plane operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/audit-control-plane-logs#control-plane-operations-for-azure-cosmos-account), then use Azure Monitor to query for these and create an alert.

Comment: Thank you Mark, just to clarify will these failover control plane events fire if the account is failing over automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an alert rule in a azure cosmos db account by adding a alert condition with a signal "Region Failed Over (Platform)"

[image: Alert Signal whenever region fails over]

This will cost $0.10 per month to get alerted on this signal in a specific cosmos db.